# How to hide rows when cell values equal to zero in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide rows when the cell values equal to 0 with some Excel VBA codes. However, the macro is not always working properly. It will hide rows even when the cell values are bigger than zero.

The scenario would be the person will input different customer IDs into a cell and hit the "Refresh" button that includes the following code. The cells will be hidden if the purchase amount shows 0. Can anyone please let me know where I did wrong?

Thank you

```
Sub HideRows()


    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Activate
    
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51").Value = 0 Then
       
            Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
             Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If


    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51").Value = 0` dosn't work as what you expected.

```vb
Sub HideRows()
    Dim c As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
        .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        For Each c In .Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51")
            If Not VBA.IsError(c.Value) Then
                If c.Value = 0 Then
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like it a lot. Just an idea to think about, to restrict it to the 5 rows (cells), you could append the `.Range(...)` to the end of the *With* line, remove the `.Rows`, and use `... In .Cells`.

Comment: It is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Entire Rows of Zero Value Cells

- Most often you don't need to activate or select (the worksheet) for a code to work. You can simply reference the objects (*workbook*, *worksheet*, *range*...) appropriately either by using the *With* statement (used in the following code; note the leading dots) or by introducing variables ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999)).
- You cannot compare the values of a range against a value in the way you were trying to. You need to loop through the cells and check each if it is equal to zero.
- Before checking each cell's value against 0, you might want to check if the cell's value is numeric to avoid a type-mismatch error if the cell contains an error.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub HideRowsInTemplate()
    
    Dim cell As Range, HideRow As Boolean
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
        For Each cell In .Range("E32,E39,E40,E50,E51").Cells
            With cell
                If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = 0 Then HideRow = True ' flag to hide
                End If
                If Not .EntireRow.Hidden = HideRow Then ' take action
                    .EntireRow.Hidden = HideRow
                End If
                HideRow = False ' reset for the next iteration
            End With
        Next cell
    End With
    
End Sub
```

### Edit

**What's with the complications in the `With cell` statement?**

Basically, you could use...

```
If .Value = 0 Then
    .EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

... or simplify with...

```
.EntireRow.Hidden = .Value = 0
```

You might want to anticipate what could go wrong. In this particular case, if you use the simple `If .Value = 0 Then` and the value is an error, a type-mismatch (run-time) error will occur. With `If IsNumeric(.Value)`, you have introduced another check (condition) that will prevent this. Of course, this all might seem ridiculous since you know that all values are numbers and there are no errors. Or do you? BTW, the boolean `False` is also numeric, and checking against `0` will result in `True` i.e. the rows of cells containing `False` will also be hidden (didn't anticipate that one).

Assuming a cell contains an error, if you use `If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value = 0 Then` (a single line), the type-mismatch error will still occur because the `IF` statement will evaluate all conditions even if the first condition is already true. Therefore you need to use two separate checks (lines) to make it work as expected.

You could use...

```
If IsNumeric(.Value) Then 
    If .Value = 0 Then
        .EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    Else
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False   
    End If
Else
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

... but you can't simplify it like in the first snippet since there are 3 cases.

To be able to simplify, I have introduced the boolean `HideRow` (more readable might be `IsRowToBeHidden`) to end up with only 2 cases...

```
If HideRow Then ' a simplified 'If HideRow = True Then'
    .EntireRow.Hidden = True 
Else
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False   
End If
```

... and after simplifying (like in the first snippet) to end up with...

```
.EntireRow.Hidden = HideRow
```

With the line `If Not .EntireRow.Hidden = HideRow Then` you are deciding if an action needs to be taken i.e. if the 'hidden state' of the row is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Quick question about the code : .EntireRow.Hidden = HideRow ' if flagged, hide
HideRow = False ' reset for the next iteration.  What is the difference between If...then..end if and yours?

Comment: Appreciate your time to answer my follow-up questions